# Align text within TEXT_ELEMENT with arcpy

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.3, text, formatting

I'm having a tough time aligning text in my text box using arcpy in ArcGIS 10.3. This is my initial text:

[image]

Now I want to insert some more text to each line and align them vertically. Normally, I would insert a `tab` (or two, if necessary), and basically it works, but in the exported PDF i get an annoying `?` for each tab I inserted.

[image]

I did it like this:

```
string.join(['UTM Zone:', '\t', utm_zone], sep='')
```

I also tried using the unicode sign for tab `u'\u0009` with the same result. [Formatting tags available in ArcMap](https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Formatting_tags_available_in_ArcMap/00s800000017000000/) does not help here, nor does [Using text formatting tags](https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s80000000p000000). I guess there is some proper way of using HTML here, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Instead of using `string.join()` I just concatenate string parts with `+` and it works fine: `text_element.text = string1 + "\t " + string2`

Comment: No, same result. `string.join()` is not the problem, it is the actual notation of `tab` I need to figure out.

Comment: What if you print to PDF instead of exporting?

Comment: If you use Arial, try with another font, see this [bug](https://support.esri.com/en/bugs/nimbus/QlVHLTAwMDA4Nzc1MA==)

Comment: As a workaround you could have 2 separate text elements, one with the fixed text and the second one with the variable text (with the anchor point on the left)

Comment: I used Calibri, as indicated in the bug report.  Can't get `arcpy.mapping.PrintMap()` to work with `Microsoft Print to PDF`, but the workaround with a second textbox does the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a combination of `str.format()` and `str.ljust()` functions to make it work. It requires some patience, and it depends on the font of the text. If you changed the font, you need also to change the settings of `ljust()`.

In this example, I used `Calibri` font as you mentioned in the comment.

Here is the code that worked for me in your case:

```
elem.text = "UTM Zone:{0}\nDatum:{1}\nEPSG code: {2}".format("38N".rjust(4),"WGS84".rjust(13),"32638".ljust(9))
```

Or you can use right-alignment `'>'` without `ljust()` and it will give you the same result:

```
elem.text = "UTM Zone:{:>4}\nDatum:{:>13}\nEPSG code:{:>7}".format("38N","WGS84","32638")
```

and here is the output in ArcGIS:

[image]

and in PDF after exporting:

[image]

Comment: You're right, it needs some patience, but the `rjust()` and `ljust()` functions look pretty to me. Thanks

Comment: You are welcome. Glad it worked :)